# How to get data out of callback function in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have problem in fetching data from http.request of node js i got data in console but when i m trying to get it out of function it is not coming in variable here is the code when i was trying to send request that is port forwarding i got response in x callback function but no data found, so anybody who knows then please let me know.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url') ,
httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var express = require("express");


 //
 // Create your proxy server
//
httpProxy.createServer(9000, 'localhost').listen(8000);

 //
// Create your target server
//
 http.createServer(function (req, res) {

res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });

//res.write('request successfully proxied!' + '\n' + JSON.stringify(req.headers, true,      2));

 var queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;


 res.writeHead(200);
 if(queryObject['id']!==undefined){
  console.log(queryObject);
  //alert(queryObject['id']);
 if(queryObject['id'].match('100'))
{
  res.write(queryObject['id']+" forwarding to another port 8000");

  //sending request
  var options = {
            host: '192.168.10.33',
            port: 8080,
            path: '/demo.js?id='+queryObject['id'],
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                accept: 'text/plain'
            }
        };

        console.log("Start conecting ...");
        var x = http.request(options,function(res2){
            console.log("Connected.");
            res2.on('data',function(data){
  //*********
 //Here is the problem occur this data i m cloud not able to print 
 //********
                console.log("data-> "+data);

            });
        });

        x.end("\n ok");
  //end 

    }
   else
   {
  res.write("listening on current port");
  }
  }
   res.end("\n end of page ");//'\n\nFeel free to add query parameters to the end of the url');
 //res.end();
  }).listen(9000);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the response data is chunked, so you need to keep loading the data and apend to a buffer and then log it to console, one the data is finished steraming.

e.g.

```
var http = require('http');

//The url we want is: 'www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
var options = {
  host: 'www.random.org',
  path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
```

Src: http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request